# Running playbook returns: Failed to connect to the host via ssh, solved by running ping all

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible playbook and I run it:

```
sudo ansible-playbook -i hosts startelk.yml -vvv
```

Every time, after I change the *hosts* file, running the same playbook results in "Failed to connect to the host via ssh". If I run

```
ansible all -m ping
```

first and then the playbook command, the playbook gets successfully started.

Does anyone know why do I have to run ping each time after changing *hosts* (or some other) file, and then my ssh connection for playbook works, otherwise no? I don't want to be running ping every time I need to change something in Ansible.

Thanks!

Comment: There are hundreds "ansible ssh" issues at SO. Follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to run "sudo ansible-playbook ..." This way the controller connects the host as root. Best practice is not to allow root ssh connections.

Best practice is to:

1. run ansible-playbook as a normal user
2. configure
   [remote_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html?highlight=remote_user#playbook-keywords)
   and
3. escalate the privilege with **become** and **become_user**.

Read more at [Understanding Privilege Escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html).

Comment: You're right, sudo was the problem, didn't know it makes the controller connect as root. Now it works, thanks!